# Передача параметров VBS-скрипту через консоль

Tags: xml, vbscript, wmi

Добрый вечер. Есть простенький скрипт, создающий XML-ку с данными о файлах:

```
Dim XMLDoc

Set XMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set headerNode = XMLDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""")
XMLDoc.appendChild (headerNode)

Set root = XMLDoc.createElement("FolderInfo")
XMLDoc.appendChild (root)

Set file = XMLDoc.createElement("Files")
root.appendChild (file)

Set objService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\CIMV2")
Set colFiles = objService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE " & _
"Drive = 'C:' AND Path = '\\Music\\'"))
For Each objFile In colFiles
    Set node = XMLDoc.createElement("FileName")
    node.Text = objFile.FileName
    file.appendChild (node)
...
```

Собственно проблема состоит в том, что я не могу понять, каким образом можно передать Drive и Path в виде консольных параметров. Пробовал с помощью Wscript.Arguments.Named.Item, но в результате получал пустой XML-файл, хотя при работе с уже заранее заданными путями все работает замечательно.

Как же правильно передать параметры, и возможно ли это при работе с WMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
pos = 0
DriveParameter = objArgs(pos)
pos = pos + 1
PathParameter = objArgs(pos)
Set colFiles = objService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive = '" & DriveParameter & "' AND Path = '" & PathParameter & "'")
```

В консоли вызывать, например, так (между параметрами пробел):

```
pathToScript\script.vbs C: \\Music\\
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, получилось!